# How to convert document from Google Docs to text file

Tags: command-line, google-drive, format-conversion, doc

How would I capture all the text in a document from Google Docs and convert it to a text file, preferably a way that can be used in a script? Would `wget` work? such as:

```
wget https://docs.google.com/document/d/documentcode > googledoc.txt
```

If so, would I be able to use a shortened URL?

Answer (score 9):

No need to pipe to other program to convert the file. You can download from Google Docs in any supported format, by using the existing parameters in the URL address.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=FORMAT
```

where:

- `FILE_ID` is string ID of target file and;
- `FORMAT` is file format of choice i.e. `txt`

Then, downloading the document from Google Docs as text file is straightforward by using `wget` or a web browser. Both methods will download the document as text file as expected.

I have tried myself and the output looks something like this:

```
$ wget https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=txt
--####-##-## ##:##:##--  https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=txt
Resolving docs.google.com (docs.google.com)...
Connecting to docs.google.com (docs.google.com)... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘export?format=txt’

    [ <=>                                    ] 649         --.-K/s   in 0s      

####-##-## ##:##:## (##.# MB/s) - ‘export?format=txt’ saved [649]
```

The URL address for other products such as Google Sheets, Google Presentation or even Google Drive would be slightly different.

In terms of documentation, the only relevant guide I found was [this dated blog post circa 2014](https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/). There is [this page of developer guide for Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads) but not useful as it is. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Google Doc as a word document with the file extension .docx. Make sure you have the docxtxt package already installed. Then run the docx2txt command followed by the name of your file. For example...

`docx2txt report.docx`