# Download spreadsheet from Google Docs in command line

Tags: command-line, downloads, google-drive

How can I download a Google spreadsheet from the command line?
This is a simple extension of the question:
[How to convert document from Google Docs to text file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998384/how-to-convert-document-from-google-docs-to-text-file/1379898#1379898)
But if I specify the format as "export?format=ods" (with "-O file.ods"), the output may be called .ods, but contains only text (.xml code, I believe).

Comment: does [this reference](https://clay-atlas.com/us/blog/2020/08/27/linux-en-wget-download-google-drive-files/) help with sheets?

Comment: Doesn't seem to, no. I think this is only for downloading files you have stored on Google Derive, not for files created in Google Docs/Sheets.

Comment: All documents - Google Docs and Sheets - **are** stored on Google Drive.

Comment: Of course that's right, sorry. The issue is really how to download it as a spreadsheet. Manually, I have the option of downloading it as .xls or .ods, but I don't know how to do that from the command line, or even, ideally, from within calc